# Spell Check with pyenchant in python for other than English

Tags: python, spell-checking, pyenchant, enchant

I am using pyenchant in python for spell checking. My code is working properly for English but now I want to make it universal for other languages also. For this, First I need to confirm that a particular word belongs the selected language or not. For example, `tree` could be english word or not, i.e., all the characters in this word belongs to `english` so it could be a valid english word. I can use python's `isalpha` function to check its belongingness with english.

`isalpha` will return false for `tree's` because `'` is not an english character.

In this case, I will split the word from any character which is not in the english dictionary.  For this, I am using below code:

```
import enchant

d = enchant.request_dict("en_US")
word = "tree's"
for a in word:
    print a
```

I will again use `isalpha` function for each character and split if function returns false.

Unfortunately, I didn't get any function similar to `isalpha` for other languages. Secondly, if I am using above code for other language then it is printing odd values in the output. For example, if I want to run it for `hindi` language,

```
# coding: utf-8
import enchant

d = enchant.request_dict("hi_IN")
word = "अभिमन्यु"
for a in word:
    print a
```

Output of this code is printing `?` in each line.

I have two questions to ask,

1) What is the right way to read characters of languages other than english ?

2) Is there any alternate function of `isalpha` for languages other than english ?

Comment: Change `"अभिमन्यु"` to `u"अभिमन्यु"` to make it a unicode string.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I did the same and found following error :


File "hindi_check.py", line 7, in <module>
    print a
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0905' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)